# How to print the sorted list with empty string first in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have the string like

```
list = ['stro', 'asdv', '', 'figh']
```

and I am using:

```
for ele in sorted(list):
    print(ele)
```

and I needed the out put like:

```
asdv
figh
stro
empty space element from list
```

I need to get the empty string at last and the other strings to be in sorted order

and if I make a reverse of the sort I would like to get the output as:

```
 empty string element
 stro
 figh
 asdv
```

Comment: your element inside the list `''` is not empty space, it's totally empty string, please adjust the expected output to reflect what you need.

Comment: Are you sure, you are doing it exactly like this? 
I get the output as you expect (on python 3.7)...

Comment: I get the output the same as you in python 3.7

Comment: Sorry for the confusion editing the problem statement

Answer (score 0):

you can print first the elements that are not empty sorted and then you can print the empty element(s):

```
from itertools import chain

for element in chain(sorted(filter(bool, my_list)), filter(lambda x: not x, my_list)):
    print(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your own key for the comparison. You want empty strings last. We can use the fact, that an empty string is *falsey*.

```
>>> bool('a')
True
>>> bool('')
False
```

`True` is bigger than `False` so non-empty strings would be sorted after empty strings but we need it the other way round.

```
>>> not 'a'
False
>>> not ''
True
```

As a second sort criterion we'll take the string itself. To do that we have to compare the tuple `(not s, s)` where `s` is the string.

We can feed this to `sorted` with the `key` parameter and a `lambda` function.

```
>>> data = ['stro', 'asdv', '', 'figh']
>>> print(sorted(data, key=lambda s: (not s, s)))
['asdv', 'figh', 'stro', '']
```

If you want it reversed add the `reverse` parameter.

```
>>> print(sorted(data, key=lambda s: (not s, s), reverse=True))
['', 'stro', 'figh', 'asdv']
```

---

Please note that I renamed your variable `list` to `data`. If you use `list` you overwrite the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) and that's a bad idea, even in an example.